# How can I insert a page to a toolBox in Qt through code?

Tags: c++, qt, toolbox

I want to click a button and insert another page into the toolBox, but I am a beginner in Qt.

I have a main function:

```
void MainWindow::addPage(){
    //Insert Page
}
```

In which I would like to call in my clicked() function.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    addPage();
}
```

Is it possible to add a page to the top of the tool box?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addItem()` method

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
     ui->toolBox->addItem(new QLabel("new Label"),"example");//you can put here another widgets instead of QLabel
}
```

or

```
void MainWindow::addPage()
{
    ui->toolBox->addItem(new QLabel("new Label"),"example");
}
```

Edit

Because you use it incorrect, constructor of QTextBrowser don't take QString (you can set only parent) [Doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html#QTextBrowser)

If you want set text to textBrowser use something like this:

```
QTextBrowser *brow = new QTextBrowser;
brow->setText("foo");
ui->toolBox->addItem(brow,"example");
```

Comment: Is there a reason as to why when I try to add a 'QTextBrowser', I get the following error? - 

    "no matching function for call to 'QTextBrowser::QTextBrowser(QString&)"

 - But when I add a 'QTextEdit' with the same parameters, it works fine?